# $a|b \land b|a \iff a = \pm b$

Tags: elementary-number-theory

Prove:

> $a|b \land b|a \iff a= \pm b$

So far I have $a|b \iff b=ka$ ($k$ is an integer), $b|a \iff a=mb$ ($m$ is an integer).
Where do I go from here?

Step by step explanation please!

Comment: should be a = mb, not ma

Comment: If $b = ka$ and $a = mb$, then $b = k(mb) = (km) b$, so $km = ....$

Comment: how does (km)b justify that a=+/-b?

Comment: @Lil Well, if $b = (km) b$, what is $km$?

Comment: Note that from $b=(km)b$ you are close to the end if you cancel $b$. Cancellation is not possible if $b=0$, so you need to deal with $b=0$ separately.

Comment: @amWhy yes it is the same question

Comment: @AndréNicolas Is it not already excluded that b=0 since b|a (or does zero divide everything trivially)?

Comment: $0$ divides $0$.

Comment: $0/0$ is indeterminate form

Comment: @MarnixKlooster amWhy also pointed another duplicate, all three are indeed the same.

Answer (score 0):

Your premises imply that there are two other integers $c$ and $d$ such that $ac=b$ and $bd=a$.
 Multiplying the second equation by $c$ on both sides we get $bdc=ac=b$. And by cancellation $dc=1$. Now the only units in the integers are $1$ and $-1$. Thus $dc=1$ implies $d=c=1$ or $d=c=-1$. Thus $a=\pm b$.

Comment: sorry can you show the cancellation steps that allowed you to get dc=1?

Comment: Well if $b=0$ then we would trivially get $a=0$, thus $a=b$. Otherwise we can assume $b\neq 0$, and since the integers are an integral domain, we can cancel.

Comment: $bdc=b\implies b(dc-1)=0\implies dc-1=0\implies dc=1$ (since we assumed $b\neq 0$)